# Multiple Rich Text Edit Fields in Edit View

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a Sharepoint site with a Master Page that has a main content area and a sidebar content area.

In one of my pages I have the need to allow the user to edit the content of the main content area and the sidebar content area from the Edit mode.

Currently, in the HTML of one of my pages, in main content area of a page (inside `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">`) i have the follow code snippet which appears to allow a HTML edit box in Edit mode.

`<SharePoint:EmbeddedFormField id="wikiField" FieldName="wikiField" ControlMode="Display" runat="server" />`

I have tried to replicate this inside the `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderSidebar" runat="server">` tag, but this simply displays the content of my main body content and does not give me the option to edit this.

When a user enters Edit mode, I need to display two rich text HTML editors, one for the main content and one for the sidebar. What HTML tags will allow me to achieve this?

I do not have access to SharePoint Designer 2013 and cannot install it for reasons I will not go into.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="PublishingPageContent" HasInitialFocus="True" MinimumEditHeight="400px" runat="server"/>
```

And add a reference to this if it's not already at the top of your master.

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

You may need to activate the publishing feature for this - I can't remember if it works without it or not.